# SwiftUI + ForEach is hitting "index out of range" while redrawing matrix with new dimensions

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach, crash, outofrangeexception

I'm using SwiftUI's ForEach to draw a Grid from a matrix in my view model that contains an equal number of rows and columns. I want to be able to tap a button and switch to a new matrix which has a different length of rows and columns (but still a square grid). **When I tap the button and switch matrices, the ForEach loops out of range while it tries to draw the smaller grid with the previous grid's dimensions.**

The matrix contains `RewardCell` elements which I've conformed to `Identifiable` and `Hashable`:

```
struct RewardCell: Identifiable {
    var isVisible: Bool = false
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let coord: CGPoint
}

// Removed after some feedback...
//extension RewardCell: Hashable {
//    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
//        hasher.combine(isVisible)
//    }
//    
//    static func == (lhs: RewardCell, rhs: RewardCell) -> Bool {
//        lhs.coord == rhs.coord
//    }
//}
```

The ForEach brute forces through the matrix while drawing it's view like so...

```
var rewardGrid: someView {
    ZStack {
        GiftView()
            .environmentObject(rewards)
        Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
            ForEach(rewards.grid, id: \.self) { row in
                GridRow {
                    ForEach(row, id: \.self) { element in
                        RewardGridCell(coord: element.coord, isEditor: true)
                            .environmentObject(rewards)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `rewards` ivar used above is an `ObservableObject` passed in as an `EnvironmentObject` and it computes the grid property this way...

```
    private lazy var muteableRewards: [Gift] = initialRewards
    
    var currentReward: Gift {
        get { muteableRewards[currentRewardIndex] }
        
        set {
            guard let index = muteableRewards.firstIndex(where: { $0 == newValue }) else { return }
            currentRewardIndex = index
            muteableRewards[index] = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var grid: [[RewardCell]] { currentReward.unlockedTileMatrix }
```

And it changes the `currentRewardIndex` like so...

```
    func nextIndex() {
        currentRewardIndex = currentRewardIndex == rewards.count - 1 ? 0 : currentRewardIndex + 1
    }
```

Inside the constructor of the `RewardGridCell` it checks if it should be drawn (`isVisible` property) and throws the error in the guard statement below:

```
    func isVisible(atCoord coord: CGPoint) throws -> Bool {
        guard let value = element(atCoord: coord)?.isVisible else {
            throw NullError(type: .optionalIsNil, subject: coord)
        }
        
        return value
    }

    func element(atCoord coord: CGPoint) -> RewardCell? {
        for row in 0..<grid.count {
            for column in 0..<grid[row].count {
                if grid[row][column].coord == coord {
                    return grid[row][column]
                }
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

The first grid drawn is 5x5 and the second grid is 3x3; which has no element when the ForEach tries the coords (4,1). I'm thinking that I screwed up the Identifiable conformance or maybe I'm not iterating through the multidimensional array correctly. **Why is this happening, and what would be the correct way to do this with SwiftUI?**

---

Okay, after some feedback I tried to ditch the matrix altogether and switch to a lazy grid by swapping out `rewardGrid` for `lazyRewardGrid` (also removed the Hashable extension that's now crossed out above):

```
var lazyRewardGrid: some View {
    ZStack {
        GiftView()
            .environmentObject(rewards)
        LazyVGrid(columns: rewards.gridColumns, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(rewards.gridAsArray) { element in
                RewardGridCell(coord: element.coord, isEditor: true)
                    .environmentObject(rewards)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's no longer a perfect square etc... but more importantly the **app still crashes in the `isVisible:atCoord` method** when I change to the new grid size.

Other changes I made during this...

```
rewards.gridColumns:

    var gridDimension: Int { /* Length/Width (e.g. 5 when grid is 5x5 */ }

    var gridColumns: [GridItem] {
        var columns = [GridItem]()
        
        for _ in 0..<gridDimension {
            let item = GridItem(.flexible())
            columns.append(item)
        }
        
        return columns
    }

rewards.gridAsArray:

    var gridAsArray: [RewardCell] {
        var array = [RewardCell]()
        for row in grid { array += row }
        return array
    }
```

Comment: Your hash function doesn't look right. All `RewardCells` with the same `isVisible` value will have the same hash value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to know about `ForEach` is it is not a loop and the item closure can be called multiple times and in any order. The behaviour is different depending on what container `View` it is in, e.g. `List`, `Table` etc.

`ForEach` requires a real `id` (that is a unique identifier property of the struct that is unique within the array and stays the same between changes) or `Identifiable` which you already have so remove all of the occurrences of `id: \.self` and the entire bad `Hashable` extension (which I'm guessing you added to make the `\.self` mistake to compile). By the way you could improve your `id` slightly like this `let id = UUID()`, from then on you can use the type `RewardCell.ID` for your functions.

Use the `id` to find things (eg `first(where:)`) instead of using indices because in Swift's world of value types the index is usually out of date, hence the out of range crashing. If you need a binding you can just do `ForEach($items) { $item in` which is convenience for a computed array of `Binding`s to find and set a value by `id`.

Comment: Okay, so when I remove the self id, the first ForEach now says that it `requires that '[RewardCell]' conform to 'Identifiable'.` The example binding `ForEach($items)` seems to be a single dimensional array. Can you include an example of how you would iterate through both dimensions of the matrix, with a new GridRow for each row?

Comment: Also, the grid itself is in a ZStack with one other element (I will update my question to show that). I guess I'm trying to figure out how the ForEach would know to start a new row when the number of rows is dynamic.

Comment: ForEach can't really be used twice for a 2d array. Try a Grid with one ForEach. Sometimes you need to transform data to pass it into these Views but can just use computed properties

Comment: I think I get what you're saying now. Thanks for getting back to me. Will try this out in the next few hours.

Comment: Edited the question with what I tried, but it's still crashing. How do I get the ForEach to recognize that it's now drawing a different (sized) grid?

Comment: So reversing the order allows me to ascend in row/column length and everything works...until I need to go back down. Don't get why it doesn't update the iterator until after trying to fill it out...I haven't been using indices since before posting the question and now I've converted to a single dimension array

Comment: your `isVisible:atCoord` is still using indicies

Comment: So I've been working on it more. I think the problem is not the index of the matrix but the index of the collection of objects that hold the matrix. Now trying to remove the `currentRewardIndex` from the VM and just have it provide methods to determine next/prev. Then I'm passing in objects into the views and not relying on tracking changes. I can also see your point about isVisible too, which I will fix next if that doesn't work.

Comment: Oh yes that is a major problem. It's best to just have one object that stores all of the model structs and pass those down the View hierarchy transforming as you go. When you pass a struct into a `View`'s init stored as a `let` it will call `body` if it has changed since last time it was init. That doesn't work with objects.